# Flow (+ React-Native): Depending function parameters

Tags: react-native, types, flowtype

I want to type a function with two params where the second one is depending on the first. My idea was to make a function type for each possible first param ("A" and "B" in example) and combine them in another type with '|' (or) condition but this results in an error "string (Expected string literal `B`, got `A` instead string literal `B`)" when I try to call the function with one of the possible values of the first param.

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

type GoToScreenA = (screen: 'A', params: { someParam: string }) => void;
type GoToScreenB = (screen: 'B', params: { someOtherParam: number }) => void;

type GoToScreen = GoToScreenA | GoToScreenB;

type Props = {
  navigation: {
    navigate: GoToScreen,
  },
};

class TestComponent extends Component<Props> {
  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('A', { someParam: 'foo' });
    // flow throws: string (Expected string literal `B`, got `A` instead string literal `B`)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I ended up with following workaround but will appreciate better answers.

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

type NavigateOption<Screen, Params> = {
  screen: Screen,
  params: Params,
};

type NavigateOptions =
  | NavigateOption<'A', { someParam: string }>
  | NavigateOption<'B', { someOtherParam: number }>;

type Props = {
  navigation: {
    navigate: (screen: string, params?: {}) => void,
  },
};

class TestComponent extends Component<Props> {
  onPress = () => {
    this.navigate({ screen: 'A', params: { someParam: 'foo' } });
  };

  navigate = (options: NavigateOptions) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(options.screen, options.params);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```